# Subclassing CompoundButton to create a three states checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm new to android dev and I like to make a 3 states checkbox for my app. How is that possible ?

It should allow the user to switch between checked/unchecked/misc states.

I'm a bit lost. Should I subclasses CompoundButton and modify the state-list drawable ? I'm actually stuck at subclassing.

Comment: Are you sure that a 3-state checkbox is what you want, rather than a set of radio buttons. Users typically expect checkboxes to be boolean, that is, on/off.

Comment: @Thomas gobernador is right...Which type of requirement you have?can you explain it in details?

Comment: I have a ListView with multiple choice activated (every line has a checkbox) and i want a checkbox on a bar upon the list to select everything, deselect everything, or go back to the previous misc selection state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was once looking for the same thing and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/ull-etsii-geobloc/wiki/ThreeStateCheckBox).  I ended up changing my requirements so cannot speak to its effectiveness, but looks like they implement the entire thing as Button, see [ThreeStateButton and ThreeStateCheckBox](http://code.google.com/p/ull-etsii-geobloc/source/browse/branches/GeoBloc2.0/GeoBloc/src/com/geobloc/widget/).